# Matlab numerical error and how to get the correct answer

Tags: matlab, rounding-error, symbolic-computation

I somehow obtain the following expression in Matlab (R2014a on W7, 64b)

```
1/1034591578977116160000*prod(1:19)*(29576428208904825-17729494921579950*k - 20479697577410832*k^2 + 13867226524449248*k^3 - 836937224095392*k^4 - 869194297188672*k^5 + 163710902234880*k^6 + 2589894827520*k^7 - 2476912838400*k^8 + 144848704000*k^9)
```

where k is initially a symbolic variable. Then I set k=10 and get the result 370371188237528 using LONGG output format. But if I put the same expression to Mathematica (substituting prod(1:19) with 19!), I get 370371188237525, which I believe is the correct answer. This seems to be a rounding error described many times on this site (is it correct?). How do I avoid it with or without Matlab symbolic toolbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [High Precision Float](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class)  class. After adding it to the path you can simply write `k = hpf(10);` before evaluating your expression. The result will be

```
370371188237525.0106290979251578332118698122510380699168308638036
```

With the Symbolic Math Toolbox I would write

```
syms k
expr = 1/1034591578977116160000*prod(1:19)*(29576428208904825-17729494921579950*k - 20479697577410832*k^2 + 13867226524449248*k^3 - 836937224095392*k^4 - 869194297188672*k^5 + 163710902234880*k^6 + 2589894827520*k^7 - 2476912838400*k^8 + 144848704000*k^9);
subs(expr, k, 10);
```

which evaluates to `3150006955960150124/8505 = 370371188237525`.

Comment: Oh my! I didnt knwo this existed! I wish I could +10.

Comment: Until I restarted Matlab I could not repeat the result (I got 2962969505900221/8 from subs(expr, k, 10)). I wonder why.. But now it's fine. Thx.